# Mostrar Toast si alguno de los tres CheckBox no está seleccionado

Tags: java, android

Este es mi código:

```
opc2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox opc2 = (CheckBox) v;
        if (opc2.isChecked()) {
            texto1.setText("Texto1");
            numero1.setText("10");
        } else {
            texto1.setText("");
            numero1.setText("");
        }
    }
});

opc3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox opc3 = (CheckBox) v;
        if (opc3.isChecked()) {
            texto2.setText("Texto2");
            numero2.setText("20");
        } else {
            texto2.setText("");
            numero2.setText("");
        }
    }
});

opc4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox opc4 = (CheckBox) v;
        if (opc4.isChecked()) {
            texto3.setText("Texto3");
            numero3.setText("30");
        } else {
            texto3.setText("");
            numero3.setText("");
        }
    }
});

// comprobar al hacer clic aquí

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent c2c3 = new Intent(Clase2.this, Clase3.class);
        startActivity(c2c3);
    }
});
```

Necesito que si hago clic en `btn1` y no está ningún `Checkbox` seleccionado envie un `Toast` y si hay al menos uno seleccionado realice la acción.

**EDITO1:** @Jorgesys esto es lo que he realizado, comprobar el `CheckBox` al hacer clic en `btn1` funciona perfectamente, pero lo que hemos realizado para acortar el código no, ya que no se envía ningún `Toast` al hacer clic en `Checkbox`

```
    Button btn1;
    CheckBox opc2,opc3,opc4;
    View.OnClickListener oclistener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        opc2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opc2);
        opc3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opc3);
        opc4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opc4);
        opc2.setTag("opc2");
        opc3.setTag("opc3");
        opc4.setTag("opc4");


        View.OnClickListener oclistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox opc = (CheckBox) v;

                if(opc.getTag().equals("opc2")){
                    CheckBox opc2 = (CheckBox) v;
                    if (opc2.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Si está seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No está seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }else if(opc.getTag().equals("opc3")){
                    CheckBox opc2 = (CheckBox) v;
                    if (opc2.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Si está seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No está seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

        }else if(opc.getTag().equals("opc2")){
                    CheckBox opc2 = (CheckBox) v;
                    if (opc2.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Si está seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No está seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 }
              }
        };


        opc2.setOnClickListener(oclistener);
        opc3.setOnClickListener(oclistener);
        opc4.setOnClickListener(oclistener);



        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (opc2.isChecked() || opc3.isChecked() || opc4.isChecked()){
                    //Alguno esta seleccionado.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alguno esta seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Realiza el intent
                    Intent c2c3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Clase3.class);
                    startActivity(c2c3);
                }else{
                    //Ninguno esta seleccionado.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ninguno esta seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Es mejor usar solo un Listener para los 3 checkbox, de lo contrario tu código creceria innecesariamente, agrego respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes definir variables de clase para los Checkbox:

```
private CheckBox opc2, opc3, opc4;
```

obtienes las referencias de los Checkbox y en tu `OnClickListener` puedes detectar si alguno de los 3 está activado:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       if (opc2.isChecked() || opc3.isChecked() || opc4.isChecked()){
         //Alguno esta seleccionado.
           Toast.makeText(this, "Alguno esta seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         //Realiza el intent
          Intent c2c3 = new Intent(Clase2.this, Clase3.class);
          startActivity(c2c3);
       }else{
         //Ninguno esta seleccionado.
           Toast.makeText(this, "Ninguno esta seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }

    }
});
```

---

En cuanto a los listener definidos por cada `Checkbox`, puedes definir sólo uno, primeramente a cada uno de los `Checkbox` le asignas un tag, por ejemplo:

```
opc2.setTag("opc2");
opc3.setTag("opc3");
opc4.setTag("opc4");
```

Declaras el `listener` y lo que realizaría al seleccionar el `Checkbox` definido por el Tag:

```
OnClickListener oclistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        CheckBox opc = (CheckBox) v;

        if(opc.getTag().equals("opc2)){
          //Realiza operación para opc2

        }else if(opc.getTag().equals("opc3)){
          //Realiza operación para opc3

        }else if(opc.getTag().equals("opc2)){
          //Realiza operación para opc4

        } 

    }
};
```

defines el mismo listener a los 3 `Checkbox`:

```
opc2.setOnClickListener(oclistener);
opc3.setOnClickListener(oclistener);
opc4.setOnClickListener(oclistener);
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta! Lo de comprobar si los CheckBox están activados funciona perfectamente, pero lo de acortar el código no, porque no me envía ningún Toast, edite la pregunta para que veas como lo hago

Comment: @UserNameYo es correcto solo recuerda primero define el listener y posteriormente lo asignas a tus checkbox: opc.setOnClickListener(oclistener); edite tu código.

Answer (score 2):

un simple if con probar si alguno esta checkeado creo que es suficiente

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (opc2.isChecked() || opc3.isChecked() || opc4.isChecked()){
                    Intent c2c3 = new Intent(Clase2.this, Clase3.class);
                    startActivity(c2c3);
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ningun check seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```